# Filters are removed after clicking on the pagination item

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

why, when turning the page, the first page parses as it should, then the filters are removed and everything is parsed at all?

```
Load: https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/searchquery=Gazer&filter=_195_588&pFilter=%2C9501%3D115448&page=1
```

Filters are removed after this page

```
    Load: https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/search?page=2
```

Here is the output from the program:

```
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM7012-J150H Toyota Prado LC150 HL', '22 392 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6510-ZD Suzuki Swift (ZD) 2004-2010', '17 592 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6510-V55', '15 992 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6509-T5 Volkswagen, Skoda, Seat, 2008-2016', '21 990 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6008-J150', '8 527 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM5510-CMF для Renault Kadjar (CMF) 2015-2017', '12 719 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Автомагнітола GAZER CM6509-GV Suzuki Grand Vitara (GV) 2015-2017', '8 846 ₴', 'КУПИТИ\nЗабрати сьогодні')
('Null', '-', '-')
Load: https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/uk/search?page=2
('Смартфон SAMSUNG Galaxy S20 FE 8/256GB Dual Sim ZBH Cloud Navy (SM-G780GZBHSEK)', '17 499 ₴', '19 999\n-2 500\n17 499 ₴\nот 730 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('Телевизор HISENSE 32A5600F', '6 499 ₴', '6 999\n-500\n6 499 ₴\nот 650 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('Стиральная машина SAMSUNG WW60J30G03WDUA', '9 999 ₴', '12 699\n-2 700\n9 999 ₴\nот 1000 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('Пылесос ROWENTA RO4811EA', '3 199 ₴', '4 399\n-1 200\n3 199 ₴\nот 320 ₴/мес\nКУПИТЬ')
('', '', '')
```

Here's the problematic function:

```
def parse(url: str) -> List[Tuple[str, str, str]]:
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')

    items = []

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5.5)
    try:
        while True:
            print('Load:', url)
            driver.get(url)

            for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card:last-child"):
                try:
                    name = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.card__title').text
                except:
                    name = ('Null')

                # Не у всех товаров есть цена
                try:
                    price = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.card-price').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    price = '-'

                try:nal = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.card__buttons').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    nal = "-"

                row = name, price, nal
                print(row)
                items.append(row)

            # Если есть кнопка перехода на следующую страницу, то продолжаем цикл, иначе завершаем
            try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-page-container"]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/nav/ul/li[6]/a')
                url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break
```

Full code: https://dpaste.org/915C

How could you implement a transition to another page by page number, and not by the pagination element?

Comment: The link you shared threw 404  Error can you share what are the filters?

Comment: Try this one please: https://www.foxtrot.com.ua/ru/search?query=Gazer&pFilter=%2C9501%3D115448